# Simple 24V high current voltage limiter

Tags: diodes, step-down

I need to power my Sure JAB 3 250 amplifier from two 12V lead batteries in series, but the recommended maximum of the  amplifier is 26V and the charging voltage of the batteries will be 28.8V.

What is a simple and effective way to make this voltage drop, to ensure not exceeding the max voltage of the amplifier?

I thought about using diodes in series or a step-down circuit for the voltage drop, but what is best practice?

The amplifier component is a TPS3116, with an onboard ADAU1701 DSP.
[TPa3116](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tpa3116d2.pdf?&ts=1589477564593)

The specific board model is Sure JAB3-250.
Its absolute maximum rating is of a TPA3116 is 30V, but recommended at 26V.

[Tpa3116 datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tpa3116d2.pdf?&ts=1589477564593)

[Sure JAB 3 product page](http://store.sure-electronics.com/product/AA-JA32172)

Comment: Give more info on the amps. It probably isn't a strict 24V limit. Or just never charge your batteries so full. Simple methods drop the voltage ALL THE TIME and waste more energy in the long run so your battery will run longer charging it to 24V and not having those devices there. Also, max current draw? Depending on current, you may have no choice but to use a switching converter and not simpler methods (which all suck anyways).

Comment: Or a double-pole, double-throw switch between the charger, batteries, and amplifiers.

Comment: It is not clear whether you are asking about the amplifier IC alone, or an amplifier that just happens to have the amplifier IC inside it.

Comment: Well i assume the question include both aspects, the absolute maximum rating is only stated in the spec sheet of the tpa chip. so the question is whether the sure amplifier board, could handle this?

Comment: If the amplifier board was intended to operate off batteries and says 24V then 28V is probably okay based on context since 24V is one of the nominal voltages for lead-acid batteries. If you provide us with a brochure or datasheet for it we could be a bit more certain.

Comment: Datasheet has been attached above

Answer (score 0):

[image]Your absolute maximum supply on that part is actually 30V.  While there's no guarantee it will make all the specifications, it won't hurt it to run it at 28.8V.  If you find the performance at this voltage unacceptable for some reason, you could look into regulation at that point, but it shouldn't cause damage.